# Problems with using Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xstate

I am stryggling to understand why setting Context with assign doesn't always work. I have a very simple application that you can find here https://codesandbox.io/embed/y0xk1mo9x9

I have this context:

```
   {
      selectedItem: 0, //Fake Value
      nextSelectedItem: 0
    }
```

which is updated by these functions:

```
const decrementNextSelectItem = (context, event) => {
  console.log("decrementNextSelectItem: " + context.nextSelectedItem);

  assign({
    nextSelectedItem:
      context.nextSelectedItem > 0
        ? context.nextSelectedItem--
        : context.nextSelectedItem
  });

  console.log("decrementNextSelectItem is now: " + context.nextSelectedItem);
};

const incrementNextSelectItem = (context, event) => {
  console.log("incrementNextSelectItem: " + context.nextSelectedItem);

  assign({
    nextSelectedItem:
      context.nextSelectedItem < 5
        ? context.nextSelectedItem++
        : context.nextSelectedItem
  });

  console.log("incrementNextSelectItem is now: " + context.nextSelectedItem);
};

const updateCurrentSelectedItem = (context, event) => {
  console.log(" updateCurrentSelectedItem: " + context.selectedItem);

  assign({
    selectedItem: context.nextSelectedItem
  });

  console.log(" updateCurrentSelectedItem is now: " + context.selectedItem);
};
```

`decrementNextSelectItem` (bound with event UP_KEY - press up arrow) and `incrementNextSelectItem` (bound with event DOWN_KEY - press down arrow) are correctly called:

```
incrementNextSelectItem: 0 
incrementNextSelectItem is now: 1 
DOWN KEY pressed 

incrementNextSelectItem: 1 
incrementNextSelectItem is now: 2 
DOWN KEY pressed 

incrementNextSelectItem: 2 
incrementNextSelectItem is now: 3 
DOWN KEY pressed 

decrementNextSelectItem: 3 
decrementNextSelectItem is now: 2 
UP KEY pressed
```

But `updateCurrentSelectedItem` (bound with event OK_KEY - press 'o' key) misteriously doesn't work as expected:

```
updateCurrentSelectedItem: 0 
 updateCurrentSelectedItem is now: 0 
OK KEY pressed
```

Is there any reason? I am getting crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your actions are defined will give you this issue, in your decrementNextSelectItem & incrementNextSelectItem you mutate the context values when doing:

```
context.nextSelectedItem++
```

or

```
context.nextSelectedItem--
```

and then in your updateCurrentSelectedItem function, you expect that using assign, like you've used in the other actions would give you the correct result:

```
assign({
  selectedItem: context.nextSelectedItem
});
```

but what you really wanted to do was to define your action like so

```
const updateCurrentSelectedItem = assign({
  selectedItem: (context, event) => context.nextSelectedItem
})
```